# Query returning rows in SQLServer but returns no row in VB.Net app

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've got a big problem with my VB.Net app :
I have a query who works perfectly in SSMS, returning 16 rows.
But when I try to execute it in my VB.Net app, I've got no rows.
Here's my code who works perfecty for filling all other DataTable of my VB.Net app (more than 200 tables). In this case, variable "a_strRequete" contains the query who works well in SQLServer, returning 16 rows.

```
 Dim v_rrqAdapteur As SqlDataAdapter
 v_rrqAdapteur = New SqlDataAdapter(a_strRequete, m_cnxSQL)
 v_rrqAdapteur.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 900
 v_rrqAdapteur.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 o_rrqTable = New DataTable
 v_rrqAdapteur.Fill(o_rrqTable)
 v_rrqAdapteur.Dispose()
```

But when I execute this in debug, the line "v_rrqAdapteur.Fill(o_rrqTable)" is executed without any errors, but give me no row. Its driving me crazy because there's no logic in this behaviour : if a query returns rows in SSMS, it must also return the same number of rows when called from VB.Net.

The only query who have this problem is using "pivot" instruction in SQLServer code. Perhaps the problem's coming from that ?

Here's the subquery who contains the pivot in my query :

```
    select id_pk, id_fk, [1.00], [1.25], [1.5]          
    from (
        select 
            id_pk,
            id_fk,
            NumericField,
            h_occ
        from [previous subquery]
    ) As Hpv
    pivot (sum(h_occ) for NumericField in(
        [1.00], [1.25], [1.5]
    )) As Spv
```

At the beginning, it was a stored procedure I've integrated to my custom DataSet. But when I see it was returning no rows in my app, I've taken the code of this stored procedure to execute it like a full text query in my code (using the code shown here), and it returns always no rows.

I've got only one server and only one DataBase, who contains all stored procedure, views and functions I need, and only one connection to this DataBase.

These's no CRM used in my code.

Thanks to all who will help.

Comment: Please show the value of the variable holding the query executed from VB and the full query used on SSMS.

Comment: The query is : select * FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[MySQLInLineFunction](2017, '08', 10025, 317, 20001178)

Comment: Well I see a huge piece missing you are not showing your connection for the object 'm_cnxSQL'.  Generally with ADO.NET you provide a connection, ensure you can get in, OPEN the connection, do something, CLOSE the connection, and best practice would be to wrap these in USING blocks to ensure that you are disposing of the reference as well.  You could be assuming a connection without a username and password where one is needed and the server is essentially saying: "Whoa I don't know who you are, I am not going to talk to you till I know who you are."

Comment: The connection "m_cnxSQL" is open with the good parameters when query is executed. This code works perfectly for filling all others tables of my app. The problem doesn't come from here

Answer (score 0):

So, I find a solution et now know from where this problem comes : it comes from the "pivot" instruction.

I've replace the pivot instruction by left join on sum subquery and it now works.

So, seems like the "pivot" instruction cannot be used in query executed from VB.Net app.

This is sad because the "pivot" instruction is very useful et quick to execute (much faster than a left join for every value of the variable to agregate).

Does somebody knows something about the use of "pivot" instruction used in queries executed from VB.Net app ?